# RadioButton being selected is wrong

Tags: c#, winforms

I am having some issues with a form I built in Visual Studio. Whenever I type in 2 numbers and hit the Modulus Radio Button. It is automatically changing to divide and I am unsure why. I have attached my code. I am putting 2 values into my Textbox and if I Check the Verbose Checkbox I have and hit Calculate. It performs division instead of Performing Modulus like i told it to.

```
namespace Module10Project
{
    public partial class frmRadioStar : Form
    {

        const byte ADD = 0;
        const byte SUBTRACT = 1;
        const byte MULTIPLY = 2;
        const byte DIVIDE = 3;
        const byte MODULUS = 4;

        public bool isPresent(TextBox txtLeft, TextBox txtRight)
        {
            if(txtLeft.Text == "" || txtRight.Text == "")
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "Please enter a number into the Textbox";
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        public bool divideByZero(TextBox Left, TextBox Right)
        {
            int leftOperand = Convert.ToInt32(Left.Text);
            int rightOperand = Convert.ToInt32(Right.Text);

            if(leftOperand == 0 || rightOperand == 0)
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "Unable to divide by 0";
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        private int equationCalculation(int Left, int Right, byte operation)
        {
            int result = 0;

            if (operation == 0)
                result = Left + Right;
            else if (operation == 1)
                result = Left - Right;
            else if (operation == 2)
                result = Left * Right;
            else if (operation == 3)
                result = Left / Right;
            else if (operation == 4)
                result = Left % Right;
            return result;
        }


        public bool isValid(TextBox Left, TextBox Right)
        {
            if (isPresent(Left, Right) && divideByZero(Left, Right))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        public frmRadioStar()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtLeft.Text = "";
            txtRight.Text = "";
            lblMessage.Text = "";
            chkVerbose.Checked = true;
            btnAdd.Focus();
            txtLeft.Focus();
        }

        private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if(isValid(txtLeft, txtRight))
                {
                    int result = 0;
                    int leftOperand = Convert.ToInt32(txtLeft.Text);
                    int rightOperand = Convert.ToInt32(txtRight.Text);

                    if (btnAdd.Checked == true && chkVerbose.Checked == true)
                    {
                        result = equationCalculation(leftOperand, rightOperand, 0);
                        lblMessage.Text = leftOperand.ToString() + " + "+ rightOperand.ToString() + " = " + result.ToString();
                    }
                    else if (btnAdd.Checked == true)
                    {
                        result = equationCalculation(leftOperand, rightOperand, 0);
                        lblMessage.Text = "The Answer is: " + result.ToString();
                    }
                    else if(btnSubtract.Checked == true && chkVerbose.Checked == true)
                    {
                        result = equationCalculation(leftOperand, rightOperand, 1);
                        lblMessage.Text = leftOperand.ToString() + " - " + rightOperand.ToString() + " = " + result.ToString();
                    }
                    else if(btnSubtract.Checked == true)
                    {
                        result = equationCalculation(leftOperand, rightOperand, 1);
                        lblMessage.Text = "The answer is: " + result.ToString();
                    }
                    else if(btnMultiply.Checked == true && chkVerbose.Checked == true )
                    {
                        result = equationCalculation(leftOperand, rightOperand, 2);
                        lblMessage.Text = leftOperand.ToString() + " * " + rightOperand.ToString() + " = " + result.ToString();
                    }
                    else if(btnMultiply.Checked == true)
                    {
                        result = equationCalculation(leftOperand, rightOperand, 2);
                        lblMessage.Text = "The answer is: " + result.ToString();
                    }
                    else if(btnDivide.Checked = true && chkVerbose.Checked == true)
                    {
                        result = equationCalculation(leftOperand, rightOperand, 3);
                        lblMessage.Text = leftOperand.ToString() + " / " + rightOperand.ToString() + " = " + result.ToString();
                    }
                    else if(btnDivide.Checked == true)
                    {
                        result = equationCalculation(leftOperand, rightOperand, 3);
                        lblMessage.Text = "The answer is: " + result.ToString();
                    }
                    else if(btnMod.Checked == true && chkVerbose.Checked == true)
                    {
                        result = equationCalculation(leftOperand, rightOperand, 4);
                        lblMessage.Text = leftOperand.ToString() + " % " + rightOperand.ToString() + " = " + result.ToString();
                    }
                    else if(btnMod.Checked == true)
                    {
                        result = equationCalculation(leftOperand, rightOperand, 4);
                        lblMessage.Text = "The answer is: " + result.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand really what is your problem, but may be you enter some numbers as input that their division result is same as their module result. Also you have some mistakes in your coding (such as defining `const` values and not using them) and some not optimized codes with overheads like your if conditions. Here is optimized version of your code. May be by clarifying your code and debugging this version you can solve your problem:

```
namespace Module10Project
{
    public partial class frmRadioStar : Form
    {
        enum OperationType
        {
            Add, Subtract, Multiply, Divide, Module
        }

        public bool isPresent(TextBox txtLeft, TextBox txtRight)
        {
            if(txtLeft.Text == "" || txtRight.Text == "")
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "Please enter a number into the Textbox";
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        public bool divideByZero(TextBox Left, TextBox Right)
        {
            int rightOperand = Convert.ToInt32(Right.Text);

            if(rightOperand == 0)
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "Unable to divide by 0";
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        private int equationCalculation(int Left, int Right, OperationType operation)
        {
            switch(operation)
            {
                case OperationType.Add:
                    return Left + Right;
                case OperationType.Subtract:
                    return Left - Right;
                case OperationType.Multiply:
                    return Left * Right;
                case OperationType.Divide:
                    return Left / Right;
                case OperationType.Module:
                    return Left % Right;
            }

            return 0;
        }


        public bool isValid(TextBox Left, TextBox Right)
        {
            return isPresent(Left, Right) && !divideByZero(Left, Right);
        }

        public frmRadioStar()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtLeft.Text = "";
            txtRight.Text = "";
            lblMessage.Text = "";
            chkVerbose.Checked = true;
            btnAdd.Focus();
            txtLeft.Focus();
        }

        private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if(isValid(txtLeft, txtRight))
                {
                    int result = 0;
                    int leftOperand = Convert.ToInt32(txtLeft.Text);
                    int rightOperand = Convert.ToInt32(txtRight.Text);

                    if (btnAdd.Checked)
                    {
                        result = equationCalculation(leftOperand, rightOperand, OperationType.Add);
                        lblMessage.Text = chkVerbose.Checked ? $"{leftOperand} + {rightOperand} = {result}" : $"The Answer is: {result}";
                    }
                    else if(btnSubtract.Checked)
                    {
                        result = equationCalculation(leftOperand, rightOperand, OperationType.Subtract);
                        lblMessage.Text = chkVerbose.Checked ? $"{leftOperand} - {rightOperand} = {result}" : $"The Answer is: {result}";
                    }
                    else if(btnMultiply.Checked)
                    {
                        result = equationCalculation(leftOperand, rightOperand, OperationType.Multiply);
                        lblMessage.Text = chkVerbose.Checked ? $"{leftOperand} * {rightOperand} = {result}" : $"The Answer is: {result}";
                    }
                    else if(btnDivide.Checked)
                    {
                        result = equationCalculation(leftOperand, rightOperand, OperationType.Divide);
                        lblMessage.Text = chkVerbose.Checked ? $"{leftOperand} / {rightOperand} = {result}" : $"The Answer is: {result}";
                    }
                    else if(btnMod.Checked)
                    {
                        result = equationCalculation(leftOperand, rightOperand, OperationType.Module);
                        lblMessage.Text = chkVerbose.Checked ? $"{leftOperand} % {rightOperand} = {result}" : $"The Answer is: {result}";
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
       }
    }
}
```